# Dynamically change content of popover in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the content of bootstrap popover dynamically but it is not working. 
Fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/62/

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="SaveChangesBtn" type="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="manual" data-content="There are no changes to save."><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbspSave Changes</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#SaveChangesBtn').on('click', function(){
    $(this).popover('hide');
    $(this).popover({content: 'Cannot proceed with Save while Editing a row.'}).popover('show');        
});
```

**Current Result:**

When Save changes button is clicked, the content 'There are no changes to save' is displayed.

**Expectation:**

The dynamic content "Cannot proceed with Save while Editing a row." should be displayed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `data-toggle="popover"` shows the popover and sets the content based on the `data-content`, while at the same time your `.on('click'...)` function hides it, changes the content, then shows it. I can see a lot of issues right there, such as too much happening at once.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$('#SaveChangesBtn').on('click', function(){
if($('.popover').hasClass('in')){
    $(this).popover('hide');
}
else
{
    $(this).attr('data-content','Cannot proceed with Save while Editing a row.');
    $(this).popover('show');
}
});
```

This way you fix the way you are showing and hiding your popover.

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/65/

Answer (score 2):

you can set a popover by javascript only if you want it to be dinamyc , you dont have to define the fields in the html.

so delete the html that make the button a popover , and create with javascript, like this:

```
   <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="SaveChangesBtn" type="button"  ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbspSave Changes</button>
```

so the button is not defining the tooltip, because you are going to create with javascript

```
      $('#SaveChangesBtn').on('click', function(){

         $(this).popover({content: 'Cannot proceed with Save while Editing a row.'});

     });
```

Answer (score 1):

I can show you my solution; You may analize it, see if it helps;

```js
$('#popover').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      // get the content based on the basis case;
      if (document.getElementById('checkbox_approval').checked == true) {
        // for the case where it is already checked
        var title = 'De-Activate Feature?';
        var content = 'some other text here. <br><br> ' +
          '<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(\'checkbox_approval\').checked=false;' +
          '$(\'#popover\').popover(\'destroy\')">' +
          'De-Activate' +
          '</button>' +
          '<button type="button"  onclick="$(\'#popover\').popover(\'hide\')">' +
          'Cancel' +
          '</button>';
      } else {
        var title = 'Activate Feature?';
        var content = 'some text here. <br><br> ' +
          '<button type="button"  onclick="document.getElementById(\'checkbox_approval\').checked=true;' +
          '$(\'#popover\').popover(\'destroy\')">' +
          'Activate' +
          '</button>' +
          '<button type="button"  onclick="$(\'#popover\').popover(\'hide\')">' +
          'Cancel' +
          '</button>';
      }

      // popover controller
      $(this).popover({
        html: true,
        title: title,
        content: content,
        placement: 'bottom',
        template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip" style="width:320px;">' +
          '<div class="arrow"></div>' +
          '<h3 class="popover-title"></h3>' +
          '<div class="popover-content"></div>' +
          '</div>'
      }).popover('show');
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
    <a id="popover" class="btn btn-danger">Click to toggle popover</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
  <label>Hidden/vissible chcker for dynamic controll
    <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="checkbox_approval" name="checkbox_approval">
  </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hope the new snippet will show you what i mean by dynamic :D

Answer (score 1):

I have been dynamically changing content of Bootstrap 4 popovers using something like this:

```
$('#SaveChangesBtn').data('bs.popover').element.dataset.content = 'Cannot proceed with Save while Editing a row.';
```

I believe once you initialize the Popovers on your page, Bootstrap then puts all the information into the data attribute `bs.popover` which Bootstrap uses to build the content of that popover.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Bootstrap 4.5.2` with `Popper 1.11` I was able to get it working using;

```js
var divElem = $('#myPopperDiv');
divElem.data('bs.popover').element.dataset.content = dynamicString;
divElem.data('bs.popover').setContent();
```

where `dynamicString` is content that is updated every 1 second using an interval.

> Note: One thing to keep in mind, is the `divElem.data('bs.popover')` doesn't exist until after the first time the user click's the pop-over button. since I'm updating it in a callback, I check

```js
if(divElem.data('bs.popover')) {
  divElem.data('bs.popover').element.dataset.content = dynamicString;
  divElem.data('bs.popover').setContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove 'data-content' attribute from button declaration.

Comment: Please include an explanation as to why, to improve quality and long term value of you answers. As is, it might better be left as a Comment.